# Compare two numbers that were previously casted as Any

Tags: scala, generics, numeric

Given two numbers like so

```
val a: Any = 1
val b: Any = 2.3
```

How can I generically compare these two numbers (regardless if one of these numbers is a `Double`, `Long`, `Float` etc.)?
Most of the solutions with implicits don't work since both values have been casted to `Any`.

Comment: Why casting it as `Any` first?

Comment: I originally receive a `Seq[Any]` of an API I cannot control (Spark) - I just simplified the example to show my issue.

Comment: I don't see where you get that from Spark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As both can be seen as `java.lang.Number`s, you can cast them to them and compare their [`doubleValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#doubleValue--)s:

```
(a.asInstanceOf[Number]).doubleValue < (b.asInstanceOf[Number]).doubleValue
```

[Scala fiddle](http://scalafiddle.net/console/c5778edf9a3ac31130f92d3bfe5587d0), [Scala JS fiddle](http://www.scala-js-fiddle.com/gist/fdc2ce079b65f53f54937bb5e727a95b?).

(Be careful with `Double.NaN`s and large long values (thanks @PeterNeyens for reminding). In case you have to handle longs too, you should use a more complex logic.)

Comment: You also loose precision if you go from `Long` to `Double`, eg `Long.MaxValue.toDouble == (Long.MaxValue - 1).toDouble`.